# How to have an image as a background in a FrameLayout and an image inside to let the user drag within the layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am looking have a layout with an image as background and add an image inside which allows me to drag within the layout only. How can I achieve it?

So let's say the red area is my framelayout and the orange box is the image:
[image]

The app loads with the orange all the to the bottom and left and then I want to let the user drag it around the red area only.

```
If (orange.x goes beyond left of the red box) {
     the orange box.x = the orange box + the orange box.width;
}
else if (orange.x goes beyond the right of the red box) {
     the orange box.x = the orange box - the orange box.width;
}

else If (orange.y goes beyond top of the red box) {
     the orange box.y = the orange box + the orange box.width;
}
else if (orange.y goes beyond the bottom of the red box) {
     the orange box.y = the orange box - the orange box.width;
}
else { // do not allow use to drag outside, if they do drag it outside leave the orange box the last known position inside the red box area
     y = orange box.y; //get x coordinate of the orange box
     x = orange box.x; //get y coordinate of the orange box
}
```

So I can setup my XML like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/redboxarea">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView  
    android:layout_width="@dimen/widthsmall" 
    android:layout_height="@dimen/heightsmall" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/orangebox"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

How can I achieve the android code to achieve what I am looking to do? Or is something else recommended?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom View (Extend the View class).

Draw the bitmap to a canvas (this is all in your custom view class)

```
   @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

//mPosX and mPosY default to 0, then on later redraws correspond to where the object was last dragged.

    canvas.drawBitmap(mSourceImage, mPosX, mPosY, null);    

}
```

Then override the onTouchEvent method

```
   @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;


        // Save the ID of this pointer ( this is for multitouch)
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
       //Get new location
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        //Compare to old location
        final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
        final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

        //set new resting location
        mPosX += dx;
        mPosY += dy;

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        //Invalidate the view and force a redraw with the new values for mPosX and mPosY.
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
```

And in your main activity code:

```
//instantiate the view object                   
touchView = new YourCustomViewClass(this, mPicturePath);

//set the size of your view
                touchView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(700, 200));

//add it to your main activity layout
                mainLayout.addView(touchView);
```

Comment: How do I write the `onCreate()` function?

Comment: You don't need one. this is a view. you will instantiate the view in your main activity as if it were any other view. I edited my answer above to show how to call it.

Comment: Where is the variable being initialized?

Comment: I already have an app which is using it but the image inside the LinearLayout does not take the image matching parent. Can you please take a look? http://pastebin.com/pCkV2M19